# AWSDynamoDb + Spring Boot + AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, devops

I have developed a spring-boot application that I'm deploying as a lambda function using a handler. Before starting the lambda function, I need to create some tables in DynamoDB. I'm unsure of the standard approach for doing this. Here are a couple of options I've considered:

1. Manually create the tables using the AWS DynamoDB console.
2. Use AWS CDK to create DynamoDB tables in the deployment pipeline. However, I'm concerned about potential issues if multiple tables are being created.

I would appreciate any guidance or best practices on how to proceed with this setup.

I tried creating tables manually.

Comment: Please check out [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what's [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You should ask a focused question showing your attempt and where it failed. As far as I see here, there's not really a question. You mention you tried creating DDB tables manually. That succeeded right? What's the question then?

Comment: *"However, I'm concerned about potential issues if multiple tables are being created."* - why?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the tables manually works fine if you don't intend to repeat the process. But if you do, or you want to have an easily repeatable infrastructure for test/dev environments then using Infrastucture as Code such as CDK is the best approach.

> However, I'm concerned about potential issues if multiple tables are being created.

You can create up to 500 tables concurrently in DynamoDB.